# UILabel numberOfLines change with animation

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` inside a `UIStackView`, and the stack view is inside another `UIScrollView`, I'm using auto layout. The label has single line (ie. `numberOfLines` equal to 1) and in a few cases I need to set it to multiline (ie. `numberOfLines` equal to 0) with an animation that expands it.

```
func expand() {
    label.numberOfLines = 0
}
```

when I click expand:

```
messageView.expand()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

However, when it expands, the label's frame isn't updated and I have to scroll (the scroll view) to make it fully visible. What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: By "Label's frame isn't update", you mean its not expanding?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh yes it's not expanding

Comment: can you add the auto layout constraints for the messageview?

Answer (score 5):

Animation of `UILabel` doesn't perform within
`UIView.animate(withDuration:)`.
This should work:

```swift
    UIView.transition(with: label, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
         self.label.numberOfLines = 0
    })
```

You can experiment with options and execution block.

Answer (score 4):

1. Have you changed the label's text?
2. Check if the autolayout is correct

Comment: Yes I changed the labels text from a single word to a long sentence, and changed its `numberOfLines` from 1 to 0.

Comment: @rocoo Please use comments for suggestions like this. An answer should provide a working solution to the issue.

Comment: In my case the problem was because of constraints.